# How to restrict SharePoint 2007 from resolving the disabled AD users?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have been working on Selective Content Migration using "SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard" from CodePlex for a particular SPList.

The migrated data is displayed in a Custom List in SP2007, in which 2 fields Preparers & Approvers (columns) are of "People & Group" data type. These two columns displays the "Name (with Presence)" of People & Group type and I am able to click the user names to open the user details for all active AD users.

How ever, some of the users are disabled in Active Directory and we are unable to populate them in SharePoint. Due to which, they are not visible in the mentioned columns. Is there a way to restrict SharePoint from resolving the inactive / disabled AD users and continue to display them in the Preparers & Approvers column?

Also what is the option to display their Name (like Sriram Bala) in a seperate column for those who are inactive in AD? Meaning, those who are disabled in AD, their name without hyper link alone should be displayed in another column say Preparer Name or something like that. I tried to use Single Line Text datatype to get the People & Group value, but it didn't work.

Please suggest the possible option to achieve this.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Central Admin (for 2007 select the appropriate SSP), you can fine tune the LDAP connection to omit different user values from the AD Sync process.

Look to add something along the lines of:

```
userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=0
```

to your LDAP filter.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your answer. In fact, I am looking at the solution from the coding perspective. From code, I would want to restrict SP to resolve AD users. Any thoughts?

Comment: Same answer, when you query the AD for the users, you use and LDAPFilter to supply the query and retrieve the correct user accounts. If you mean, querying the People Profiles for disabled accounts, this isn't stored in the profile AFAIK.

Comment: Bu tis there any point in syncing disabled user account with SharePoint? Unless theres a valid reason, I'd filter there to start with.

Comment: The reason behind this is, some of the users in AD are not part of the organization. So their user profile is disabled in AD. Whatever records they have worked on, it still shows their name, but SharePoint is unable to resolve them against AD as they are inactive. I have a custom list in which I am displaying those users (Acive / Inactive). For all the inactive users, the field displays a blank value. Which is why, I want SharePoint not to resolve those users and continue to display their name. Is this possible Paul ?